# Estou tendo problema ao imprimir uma variavel em meu programa

Tags: c, array, string, funções, struct

Estou fazendo um programa que simula um banco, na função `criarpessoafisica`
estou tentando fazer com que o algoritmo verifique se o cpf já esta cadastrado, mas não está dando certo ! Por algum motivo ele imprimi o cpf normal nessa linha

```
 printf("\ncpf %s\n",cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[num].cpf );
```

Mas nessa linha não;

```
printf("cpf %s ver %s i %i\n",cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[i].cpf, verificador, i  );
```

código completo;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int num=0;
int numcontas=0;
int tipoconta=-1;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct Pessoa{
  char nome [100];
  char endereco [100];
  char telefone [12];
  float renda;
  int tipopessoa; //1=fisica e 2=Juridica
  char cpf [20],cnpj [20];
}pe;

typedef struct Contacomum{
  char senha [5];
  char numconta [4];
  char agencia [4];
  float saldo; 
  pe pessoas [100];
  int pessoa;
}cc;
typedef struct contabancaria{
  cc cocom [20];
}cb;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gotoxy(int x, int y){
     SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){x-1,y-1});
     //muda o cursor para a posição x,y
   }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void fazerjanela (int ci,int li,int lf,int cf){
  //faz uma janela c=coluna l=linha i=incial f=final
  int i,y;
  for ( i = ci+1; i < cf; i++) {
    gotoxy(i,ci);printf("%c",196 );
  }
  for ( i = ci+1; i < cf; i++) {
    gotoxy(i,lf);printf("%c",196 );
  }
  for ( i = li; i < lf; i++) {
    gotoxy(ci,i);printf("%c",179 );
  }
  for ( i = li; i < lf; i++) {
    gotoxy(cf,i);printf("%c",179 );
  }
  gotoxy(ci,li);printf("%c",218 );
  gotoxy(cf,lf);printf("%c",217 );
  gotoxy(cf,li);printf("%c", 191);
  gotoxy(ci,lf);printf("%c", 192);
  gotoxy(cf,lf+1);printf("\n");
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void criarpessoafisica (cb *cb){
  int tam, flag=0, cout, i=0, j=0;
  char verificador [14];
  if (tipoconta == 0) {
    cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[num].tipopessoa = 1;
    system("cls");    fazerjanela(1,1,15,50);
    gotoxy (15,2); printf("Cadastro de Pessoa Fisica");
    gotoxy (3,4);   printf("Pesssoa N00%i ", num+1);
    gotoxy (3,6);   printf("Nome: ");fflush (stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[num].nome);
    gotoxy (3,7);   printf("Endereco: ");fflush (stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[num].endereco );
    gotoxy (3,8);   printf("Telefone: ");fflush (stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[num].telefone );
    gotoxy (3,9);   printf("Renda Mensal: ");fflush (stdin);
    scanf("%f", &cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[num].renda );
    do {
      flag=0;
      gotoxy (3,12); printf("                                            ");
      gotoxy (3,14); printf("                                            ");
      gotoxy (3,10); printf("                                     ");
      gotoxy (3,10); printf("CPF: ");fflush (stdin);
      scanf("%s", &verificador );
      printf("\nverifi %s", verificador);
      system("cls");
      strcpy (cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[num].cpf,verificador);
      printf("\ncpf %s\n",cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[num].cpf ); sleep(1);
      for ( i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cout=0;
        printf("cpf %s ver %s i %i\n",cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[i].cpf, verificador, i  );sleep(1);
        for ( j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
          if (verificador[j] == cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[i].cpf[j]) {
            cout++;printf("\ncout %i", cout);
            if (cout == 11) {
              flag=1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (flag == 1) {
        gotoxy (3,12); printf("Error CPF já cadastrado !");
        gotoxy (3,14); system ("PAUSE");
      }
    } while(flag);
    gotoxy (3,12); printf("Pessoa cadastrada com sucesso !");
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void cadastrarpessoa (cb *cb){
  int pos1=1;
  char opc;
  do{
      system("cls"); fazerjanela (1,1,15,50);
      gotoxy (6,5);  printf("Que tipo de pessoa deseja cadastrar ?");
      gotoxy (6,8);  printf("   Pessoa Fisica");
      gotoxy (25,8); printf("   Pessoa Juridica");
      gotoxy (40,14);printf("   Voltar");
      switch (pos1){
        case 1: gotoxy(6,8);    printf("-> Pessoa Fisica");break;
        case 2: gotoxy(25,8);   printf("-> Pessoa Juridica");break;
        case 3: gotoxy(40,14);  printf("-> Voltar");break;
      }
       opc=getch();
       if (opc==-32){ //tecla especial necessita pegar segundo valor
          opc=getch();
          switch (opc) {
            case 75:pos1--; break; //SETA PRA CIMA
            case 77:pos1++; break; //SETA PRA BAIXO
          }
       }
     if (pos1==0) pos1=3;
     if (pos1==4) pos1=1;
     if (opc == 13) //ENTER
       switch (pos1){
         case 1:
           criarpessoafisica (&cb);
           opc=27;
         break;
         case 2:
           opc=27;
         break;
         case 3:
                opc=27;
         break;
       }
   }
   while (opc!=27);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void criarcontacomum(cb *cb){
  int pos1=1;
  char opc;
  tipoconta = 0;
  do{
    system ("cls");  fazerjanela(1,1,15,50);
    gotoxy (2,4);   printf("-----------------(Conta Comum)------------------");
    gotoxy (5,7);   printf("   Cadastrar Nova Pessoa ");
    gotoxy (5,9);   printf("   Usar Pessoa Existente ");
    gotoxy (2,12);  printf("------------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy (42,14); printf("   Sair");
    switch (pos1){
      case 1: gotoxy(5,7);  printf("-> Cadastrar Nova Pessoa ");           break;
      case 2: gotoxy(5,9); printf("-> Usar Pessoa Existente ");        break;
      case 3: gotoxy(42,14);printf("-> Sair");                  break;
    }
     opc=getch();
     if (opc==-32){ //tecla especial necessita pegar segundo valor
        opc=getch();
        switch (opc) {
          case 72:pos1--; break; //SETA PRA CIMA
          case 80:pos1++; break; //SETA PRA BAIXO
        }
     }
   if (pos1==0) pos1=3;
   if (pos1==4) pos1=1;
   if (opc == 13) //ENTER
       switch (pos1){
         case 1:
          cadastrarpessoa (&cb);
          //gerarconta (&cb);
          num++;  numcontas ++;
         break;
         case 2:

         break;
         case 3:
                opc=27;
         break;
       }
   }
   while (opc!=27);
 }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void criarconta(cb *cb) {
  int pos1=1;
  char opc ;
  do{
      system ("cls");  fazerjanela(1,1,15,50);
      gotoxy (2,4);   printf("--------------------(Conta)---------------------");
      gotoxy (5,6);   printf("   Conta Comum ");
      gotoxy (5,8);   printf("   Conta Especial ");
      gotoxy (5,10);   printf("   Conta Poupanca ");
      gotoxy (2,12);  printf("------------------------------------------------");
      gotoxy (42,14); printf("   Sair");
      switch (pos1){
        case 1: gotoxy(5,6);  printf("-> Conta Comum");           break;
        case 2: gotoxy(5,8);  printf("-> Conta Especial");        break;
        case 3: gotoxy(5,10);  printf("-> Conta Poupanca" );       break;
        case 4: gotoxy(42,14);printf("-> Sair");                  break;
      }
       opc=getch();
       if (opc==-32){ //tecla especial necessita pegar segundo valor
          opc=getch();
          switch (opc) {
            case 72:pos1--; break; //SETA PRA CIMA
            case 80:pos1++; break; //SETA PRA BAIXO
          }
       }
     if (pos1==0) pos1=4;
     if (pos1==5) pos1=1;
     if (opc == 13) //ENTER
       switch (pos1){
         case 1:
          criarcontacomum (&cb);
         break;
         case 2:
          //criarcontaespecial (&cb);
         break;
         case 3:
         //criarcontapoupanca (&cb);
         case 4:
          opc=27;
         break;
       }
   }
   while (opc!=27);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
  system("mode con:cols=50 lines=17");
  cb contabancaria;
  int pos1=1;
  char opc;
  //lerarquivo (&contabancaria); //arumar <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<------
  do{
      system("cls"); fazerjanela (1,1,15,50);
      gotoxy (2,4);   printf("--------------------(Conta)---------------------");
      gotoxy (5,8);   printf("   Criar ");
      gotoxy (31,8);  printf("   Acessar ");
      gotoxy (2,12);  printf("------------------------------------------------");
      gotoxy (42,14); printf("   Sair");
      switch (pos1){
        case 1: gotoxy(5,8);  printf("-> Criar");       break;
        case 2: gotoxy(31,8); printf("-> Acessar");       break;
        case 3: gotoxy(42,14);printf("-> Sair");           break;
      }
       opc=getch();
       if (opc==-32){ //tecla especial necessita pegar segundo valor
          opc=getch();
          switch (opc) {
            case 75:pos1--; break; //SETA PRA ESQUERDA
            case 77:pos1++; break; //SETA PRA DIREITA
          }
       }
     if (pos1==0) pos1=3;
     if (pos1==4) pos1=1;
     if (opc == 13) //ENTER
       switch (pos1){
         case 1:
          criarconta(&contabancaria);
         break;
         case 2:
          //acessarconta(&contabancaria);
         break;
         case 3:
          opc=27;
         break;
       }
   }
   while (opc!=27);
   system("cls");
   printf("\nPrograma Finalizado com suscesso !\n");
}
```

Comment: se código está difícil de ler, tudo junto, sem linhas em branco separando nada...aparentemente você não está incrementando a variável "numcontas", portanto toda sua entrada de dados é feita apenas na conta de índice 0

Comment: Estou sim, após essa função tem uma linha "numcontas++;", mas o problema é que não está mostrando ```cb->cocom[numcontas].pessoas[i].cpf```

Answer (score 0):

Apenas olhando o código que você postou não é possível saber porque não funciona do jeito que você quer, provavelmente tem erro de lógica na parte que não foi mostrada.

Mas é possível fazer algumas considerações:

1 o formato correto para ler até o final da linha é "%[^\n]", sem o "s" após o fecha colchete; na prática isso **normalmente** não causa problemas, mas é bom ficar de olho

2 a maneira correta de consumir o "\n" após um scanf("%[^\n]") não é através do "fflush(stdin);"...isso não é padrão, é uma extensão da do Visual C++ que não funciona no Linux, por exemplo...o correto é colocar um espaço no começo do formato no **próximo** scanf que for feito, assim: scanf("%[^\n]");... scanf(" %[^\n]")

3 **sempre** é preciso verificar o retorno do scanf, para verificar se não houve algum erro na entrada de dados, assim:

```
n = scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
if (n != 2)
{
  // tratar erro na entrada de dados!
  ....
}
```

Isso é o possível dizer.

ATUALIZAÇÃO

Como o programa é meio grande, e eu não consigo compilar (foi feito para Windows, não compila no Linux) é difícil descobrir alguma coisa, mas achei estranho essas linhas

```
 cadastrarpessoa (&cb);
 //gerarconta (&cb);
 num++;  numcontas ++;  // <--------------
```

A impressão superficial que tenho é que para a conta 0 está sendo criada a pessoa 0, para a pessoal 1 está sendo criada a pessoa 1 (sem criar a pessoa 0), e assim por diante.

Como disse acima, acho que é um erro de lógica, mas fica difícil dizer onde, teria que analizar o programa inteiro. Não parece ser um erro de C.

Comment: Entendi, mas o problema e que ele lê a variável corretamente, mas dentro do for ele não mostra a mesma coisa que mostra antes do for. Coloquei meu código completo funcionando caso você queira dar uma olhada